# Showing cause of errors during bicep deployments from azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-bicep

I am trying to execute the following task to update my service bus. However , when I tried to execute the following task,

```
                - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
                  inputs:
                    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
                    azureResourceManagerConnection: '$(azureServiceConnection)'
                    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
                    resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupName)'
                    location: '$(location)'
                    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
                    csmFile: 'biceps/main.bicep'
                    overrideParameters: '-sbusParams $(sbusParam)'
                    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

I got the following error:

> ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see
> https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.

> ##[error]Details:
> ##[error]DeploymentFailed: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for
> details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage
> details.
> ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your
> issue is addressed: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting

I guess the issue may be because of my service bus is basic tier and it only supports queue while I am trying to create topic and subs.
But, The questions are:

1. how do I get the detail information of what's wrong? With that error message alone i cannot troubleshoot and look for specific details.
2. what does it mean by "Please list deployment operations for details." ? How do i list deployment operations for details? Thanks!

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines), you could always use the `deploymentOutputs` to get the full details

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do for this would be to go into the Azure Portal and access the deployment log. This can be access by checking the resource group you are deploying into:

[image]

After clicking the deployment you will see the failed attempt you are referencing. If you click this it will show you the ARM template that was transpiled from your Bicep.  Additionally you might see the inner error involved.